# Как правильно организовать разные шаблоны для одинаковых типов страниц wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

я организовал админку вот таким образом: http://joxi.ru/Drlvw5zFVGlW82 все эти страницы корректно выводятся через один файл в моём шаблоне, это page.php ( http://joxi.ru/Y2L6dgeF7MBkNr ) но мне нужно выводить их по-разному, у меня сейчас что-то вроде `case` ну только с помощью `if elseif` ( http://joxi.ru/4AkyVBzio0zPOm ) вроде работает, но очень грязно. Кто интегрировал верстку на вордпресс подскажите как правильно разрулить. Ах да ещё и второй уровень тоже.

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос. Картинки - в пост, а код оформить кодом а не картинками.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать в папке темы файл *.php

```
В его начале такой код:
<?php
/*
Template Name: Главная страница
*/
```

Так создается шаблон страницы, этот файл будет использоваться при построении страниц у которых выбран этот шаблон.

Чтобы выбрать этот шаблон нужно зайти в атрибуты страницы и изменить шаблон. См. фото: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]